# Laravel: encrypt the uploaded file/image

Tags: laravel, encryption, laravel-encryption

I am new in laravel, try to encrypt the uploaded file. Here is my controller:

```
if ($file != null && !empty($file)) 
{
   $userfile = DNEUser::find($lastUserId);
   $user_store_pic = $request->file('user_store_pic');
   $fileContent = $user_store_pic->get();
   $encryptedContent = encrypt($fileContent);
   $s3 = \Storage::disk('uploads');
   //$array=explode(" ",$encryptedContent); 
   $user_store_pic_name = $lastUserId.'_'.time().'.' .$encryptedContent->getClientOriginalExtension();
   $filePath = 'store/'.$user_store_pic_name;
   $s3->put($filePath, file_get_contents($encryptedContent));
   $userStorePicName = $filePath;
   $userfile->user_store_pic = $userStorePicName;
   $userfile->save();
}
```

I am trying to encrypt the file as per https://stefanzweifel.io/posts/how-to-encrypt-file-uploads-with-laravel/

but I got an error when I submit the form:

> "ymfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError
>   (E_ERROR) Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on
>   string"

I try to convert into an array using explode but it shows the same error for an array:

> "Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on array"

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `$user_store_pic->getClientOriginalExtension();`
 in place of `$encryptedContent->getClientOriginalExtension()`

It may help you.

Comment: I already try that, its shows ErrorException (E_WARNING), "file_get_contents(eyJpdiI6Im5qVHI0TVBTNEtWSHorbXY0RVB4eHc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiZTk1ZmpSUjVENmlBMlJ5TWsxa3hFQnNPdnpzTmdLeVU5RWQySGNZdkVLRGs2bzRId3dZT2ZiVDdGTFBjTlZNcm ▶"

Comment: Try to use this:
```
$file = $request->file('attachment');

// Get File Content
$fileContent = $file->get();

// Encrypt the Content
$encryptedContent = encrypt($fileContent);

// Store the encrypted Content
$s3->put($filePath, $encryptedContent);
```

Comment: still received same error: "Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on string"

Comment: Have you got error "Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on string" after using  this "$user_store_pic->getClientOriginalExtension()" ?

Comment: @SagarParikhSGR You are doing a poor job debugging your code. How about figuring out what the variables are before using them. This way you are not assuming what the variables content is. Laravel includes a nice helper function call `dd()`

Comment: @RahulRai yes its shows same error after use this  "$user_store_pic->getClientOriginalExtension()"